# Ubuntu Server 15.10 Hide Auto-Login Startx text on boot up

Tags: boot, xorg, login, compiz

I have ubuntu server 15.10 running compiz as the window manager. On boot up I am starting the compiz session with startx in my .profile and then running a GTK fullscreen application that the user is "locked" into (basically a kiosk computer). I am trying to hide ALL text output to the screen and I am getting hung up on the TTY1 output from "startx". Is there a way to hide that tty1 autologin and startx text so that it just boots directly into the GTK application.

**Note: trying to not use a DM due to certain criteria set from customer.**

I have this in my .profile to start my compiz session

```
[[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && exec startx
```

I have hidden most of the text output on boot up in the /etc/default/grub file with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```